# How to leverage and use the HTML content and TS methods of componentX while you are in componentY?

Tags: angular

This is an angular 2+ question and about a concept cross-component access ( which I just coined ), and whether it is possible to achieve or not.

Here is the scenario:

I got this button that lets me toggle the `#sidenav`

```
<button type="button"   mat-icon-button     (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
    <mat-icon>
        search
    </mat-icon>
</button>
```

Then I got the corresponding `#sidenav` content that shows up when the button above is clicked.

```
<mat-sidenav    #sidenav  >

    HTML to go here...

</mat-sidenav>
```

This is working. Everytime I click the button, I can see the section with the text HTML to go here on and off.

But, here is an extremely challenging wish that I want to satisfy.

Say, I got another component with a few vars and methods in it. 
Let's call it `XComponent`

Let `XComponent.ts` have these;

```
x=10; 

alertX(){
    alert(this.X);
}
```

and `XComponent.html` to have this

```
<div id="take-me-and-show-my-contents-in-the-sidenav-when-button-is-clicked">
    <button (click)='alertX()'></button>
</div>
```

Here is the challenging question;

Can I take the div with the `id` ( take-me-and-show... ) above and programmatically show its contents in the other component's `#sidenav` content area? So the  `HTML to go here` gets replaced with `<button (click)='alertX()'></button>`

Assuming that is possible, how will the button's (click) event which calls the XComponent's alertX will still continue to work while running in the 1st component?

Or is it just impossible to do this kind of cross-component access?

Comment: Is your div the full extent of XComponent.html? If so, I'm guessing [Dynamic Component](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) has the intention you want. As for the click event, XComponent will have to emit it to it's parent.

Comment: Thanks Richard. But, XComponent have a few divs, so to answer your question; No. it is not the entire HTML.

Comment: I'm almost looking for a feature that will make the following dream come true:  (click)='XComponent.ts->alertX()' so angular can find where alertX() live. And for the other one {{ XComponent.html->ThatDiv }}. :)

Comment: Cheers. So, it looks like ViewChild or ContentChild might be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Please excuse the example code, it's a bit rough-and-ready.

Essentially, my first idea is to add some plumbing in the form of `ViewChild`'s in XComponent. This allows turning on and off various divs depending on context in which XComponent is used.

I'm trying to keep the code within the bounds of standard Angular usage, hence the ViewChild's and ngIf's (i.e not using DOM manipulation, even [hidden]).

Here's a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/WK238VHku5n22lyKVkkV?p=preview)

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'x-component',
  template: `
  <div #takeme>
    <button (click)='alertX()'></button>
  </div>
  <div #another1 *ngIf="showAll">
    Hello x-component
  </div>
  <div #another2 *ngIf="showAll">
    Hello again x-component
  </div>
 `,
})
export class XComponent {
  @ViewChild('takeme') takeMe: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('another1') another1: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('another2') another2: ElementRef;
  name:string;
  @Input() showAll = true;

  alertX() {
    console.log('alertX()')
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>

      <br/><hr/>
      I'm a 'normal' usage of XComponent
      <x-component></x-component>

      <br/><hr/>
      Pretend I'm a side-nav
      <x-component [showAll]="false" #xcomponent></x-component>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  @ViewChild('xcomponent') xcomponent: ElementRef;
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    console.clear()
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.xcomponent.alertX = this.myAlertX
  }

  myAlertX() {
    console.log('parent alertX')
  }
}
```

The next thing to try might be dynamically adding `this.xcomponent.takeMe` to the side-nav template.

---

**Using Renderer2**

Here's a version using Angular's Renderer2 that is a little less invasive of XComponent.

Here's the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/dTkLGVBtrhicl7HCl84q?p=preview)

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'x-component',
  template: `
  <div #takeme>
    <button (click)='alertX()'></button>
  </div>
  <div #another1>
    Hello x-component
  </div>
  <div #another2>
    Hello again x-component
  </div>
 `,
})
export class XComponent {
  @ViewChild('takeme') takeMe: ElementRef;

  alertX() {
    console.log('alertX()')
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>

      <br/><hr/>
      I'm a 'normal' usage of XComponent
      <x-component></x-component>

      <br/><hr/>
      Pretend I'm a side-nav
      <div #takemediv></div>
      <template>
        <x-component #xcomponent></x-component>
      </template>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {

  @ViewChild('xcomponent') xcomponent: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('takemediv') divHost;

  name:string;
  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {
    console.clear()
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.renderer.setProperty(this.divHost.nativeElement, 'innerHTML', 
        this.xcomponent.takeMe.nativeElement.innerHTML);
    const button = this.divHost.nativeElement.querySelector('button');
    this.renderer.listen(button, 'click', () => this.myAlertX())
  }

  myAlertX() {
    console.log('parent alertX')
  }
}
```

Essentially, we create an instance of XComponent within `<template>` tags, which the DOM won't display.

Then we take the div we want and place it into a host div using Renderer2, and also hook up the click event with the same tool.

The advantage over the first version is that XComponent no longer needs *ngIf attributes on div's that we don't want to show (since we are extracting the specific div we **do** want to show).

Comment: I'm going to test this Richard. Thank you very much for taking the time to thinking thru about this. Appreciated.

Comment: Cheers. Still working on a version with less impact on XComponent.

Answer (score 0):

For Component communication the best reference is still Tour Of Heroes:

[parent=>child](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding) (using @Input() and either a stream of values or a value directly - the latter handles ChangeDetection automatically on value change)

[child=>parent](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event) (using @Output() and EventEmitter, but you could use any other observable, Like Subject or BehaviorSubject)

[distant relatives or siblings](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service) (using an injected service as the entity containing the streams)